# count from right side of a variable and remove remainder

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch files and I can't even grasp how to begin a batch script to accomplish what I really need. I'm not sure if it's even possible, but I hope somebody can help, it would be very much appreciated. What I want to do is count from right to left 17 characters and remove the remainder. Below is an example:

```
A.C.D,ABCDEFGH,ABCDEFGH
A.F.N,R,ABCDEFGH,ABCDEFGH
L.V.X.A.C.D,ABCDEFGH,ABCDEFGH
```

OUTCOME

```
ABCDEFGH,ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGH,ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGH,ABCDEFGH
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance if anybody can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use Bash [**substring extraction**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTREXTR01):

```
myvar=A.C.D,ABCDEFGH,ABCDEFGH

echo ${myvar:(-17)}
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nelson :)   I'll see if i can manage anything out of that. I also should have mentioned its reading thousands of lines from a text file and i want to strip those remainding characters after it finds 17 positions from the right hand side. Thanks again, much appreciated  ;)

Comment: Ok, try it, and remember to accept answer if this finally help you to solve your problem.